# Convert bytes to float or string in python

Tags: python, sockets, utf-8, utf-16

I am a beginner for both python and socket programming and am seeking your help.

I am sending a text command using send in socket programming to an industrial machine. It is required that the text is converted to bytes in socket programming. So  I do this:

```
client.send(b'command1')
var1=client.recv(1024)

client.send(b'command2')
var2=client.recv(1024)

# I receive the following for var1 and var2.

var1=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03n\x80\x01'
var2=b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x030\xb0\x01'
```

It throws an error when I try to decode it using utf-8 saying "cant decode byte in 7th position" for both the cases. I tried utf-16 by removing the first four or last four characters and it works but shows Chinese characters. The user interface of machine is actually in English!

I know that var1 should be a string and var 2 should be float.

Just for testing, I tried conversion to hex and list and it works; but I am not sure how to proceed to get the actual string and float.

Appreciate any help; thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an extra character in your hexidecimal bytes `\x03n` <- the "n" and `\x030` <- extra "0"

Comment: Yes, I observed that. I do not think it is causing the problem because if I delete \x00 in the beginning, it works with utf-16 and gives "rarely used" Chinese character.

Comment: This is a problem with using the wrong RS232 cable (null vs straight) and not a programming issue. The arbitrary code \x00 is thrown back by the port due to wrong cabling. This topic may hence be closed.